# How to access UNIX-based device's directories?

Tags: unix

I have a telecom device ([EJOIN](http://en.ejointech.com/)). I can access log files from device's admin console website *(need to login with id and password)* but files are in limited counts (5 is most). I can directly download specific log files by URL like

> http://{host}:{port}/opt/ejoin/var/log/messages.043.log

but I would like to browse all log files instead of given 5 log files by directory `http://{host}:{port}/opt/ejoin/var/log/`. Has there any softwares or tools to achieve it from Window OS ?

I don't have much experince about UNIX and such kind of things. But I do believe there has some ways to access those. I'm not sure this device is available FTP. I've tried with WinSCP tool but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

The common way is SSH. WinSCP will allow you to access files over SSH in a comfortable GUI from Windows. You would first have to enable SSHD on the device.

It depends upon device support. If you can turn on FTP or SSH then you can do it. If the device doesn't let you turn on the required services then you can't.

Check the web console for "Services". Then enable FTP or SSH service.